# How do I insert an entity with 2sxc in a razor script?

Tags: razor, crud, 2sxc

Instead of reading data out of 2sxc, I want to pump a list of data into a 2sxc stream. As all should run on the server-side within a razor script, I don't want to use WebApi and post every single entity.

It is possible to do CRUD operations within a razor script? Any example/demo available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it in the documentation:

1. App.Data.Create(contentTypeName, values, userName)
2. App.Data.Update(entityId, values, userName)
3. App.Data.Delete(entityId, userName)

https://2sxc.org/en/docs/Feature/feature/3360
https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/razor-app

Comment: You should also check out this related Question/Answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306880/how-can-i-add-a-value-to-fields-of-type-entity-when-using-app-data-create

Answer (score 0):

I found the page, which might interest you (official GitHub of 2sxc):
https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/razor-dnn

Comment: I did search the wiki and documentation pages before. That link points to how to access the dnn object and has nothing to do with CRUD against 2sxc streams.